# What chord name is Bb - Eb - Ab

Tags: theory, piano, sheet-music

I'm new to music theory and just finished some basic stuff like scales, arpeggios, etc. I'm learning a song(Ab Maj) but can't figure out what chord name is that has Bb - Eb - Ab in the right hand and Eb in the bass(on piano). I'm guessing it's Ab maj 9th chord or Ab sus2 chord but not sure. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a dupe - or is it?

Comment: @Tim, Do you mean something is wrong with my question or something else? let me know, I will update then. Always thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this kind has been asked previously. Nothing wrong with the question per se. However vtc as asking about a particular chord is offside anyway. Sorry!

Comment: Welcome! You can check out [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be Ebsus4. This works as follows: Eb chord consists of notes: Eb-G-Bb, and sus4 means to replace the third, G, with the fourth, Ab.

As you wrote, it could be also second inversion of Absus2.

But it depends on the context. Especially since sus or quartal chords have a bit ambiguous sound, so depending on what was before and what follows the interpretation might be different.

Edit after the score was added: This is Ebsus4. Note how the suspended note Ab resolves down to G, so that the chord becomes Eb, which is the dominant in the key of Ab. This is a common structure in classical music.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just added a screenshot of the sheet. it's "When you tell me that you love me" song.

Comment: @Alex please see the edit

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much for your detailed explaining!!!

Comment: Proper name - Eb ret 2. 4ths are suspended, 2nds retarded.

Comment: "Edit after the score was added: This is Ebsus2" there's no F.  Did you mean sus 4?  (cc: @Tim)

Comment: @phoog - in this case, yes. Merely pointing out that sus2 is in reality a misnomer - sus2 should be called ret2. Sus4, when it exists, is a suspended 4. The same 3 notes will always constitute a sus4 *and* a 'sus2', as an inversion, if you like.

Comment: This is definitely not Ebsus2. That would be Eb - F - Bb. This is Ebsus4, as you originally wrote. Given the context, it's interesting to note how similar it is in content and function to Bbsus4 (or Bbsus4/Eb, as the case may be).

Comment: @Tim sus2 is correct when the 2 is resolving downward. It a retardation when it resolves upward.

Comment: @Aaron in classical theory -- or at least in 18th century figured bass -- a 2 that resolves downward is typically called a 9 instead.  The figure 2 denotes an inverted 7th that resolves by motion in the bass.  But I've never seen a lead sheet with "ret2" nor do I expect that many musicians would know what it means or why.

Comment: @Aaron - when there's M2 instead of m/M3 generally, that 2 resolves both ways, resulting in am or M triad. difficult to say which way that 2 actually moves, I'd have thought. I see a question arriving...

Comment: Thank you all here! I just realized again that music theory is so difficult for me. hah!